# Asp.net core 3.1 windows authentication and authorization similar to asp.net 4.x web.config roles

Tags: asp.net-core

i'm in the process of converting an older asp.net 4.x site to asp.net core 3.1 . the older site used web.config and roles using local computer user groups not AD groups. I can't seem to find an easy way to implement this in .net core, i've hit several posts and tried but to no luck.

So here is an example of the previous asp.net 4.x web.config

```
  <location path="reporting">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles=".\team_reporting" />
        <allow roles=".\team_admins" />
        <allow roles=".\sites_admins" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

so the path or directory "reporting" had 3 different Local Windows Groups called "team_reporting" , "team_admins", and "sites_admins" defined. These local groups would have AD user accounts in them.  So if active dir account "ad_domain\john" accessed the site , if he was in either of the 3 groups he could access reports directory.

i tried this method which did not work for me
https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2018/06/06/asp-net-core-2-quick-and-dirty-windows-authentication/
and a few others.

I'm already able to get the AD user's AD name/ID in asp.net core but just looking for how i can implement roles auth in asp.net core using AD user ID that are configured in Windows Local Groups on the server ?

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to use AD groups in this post which also worked for local groups as well, i had tried this previous and it did not work, but works now :) i also explain why it wasn't working when i tried it before.

https://forums.asp.net/t/2152453.aspx

also using ".\local_group_name" did not work so i had to use the server name "webserver\local_group_name" to make it work. in previous asp.net 4.x i could use .\ fine. So when i first tried this solution in my Startup.cs file i had UseAuthorization before UseAuthentication

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

After placing Auth before Authorize it worked :)

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```